Market making - widening orders based on volatility, constant bps or multiply spread by factor?
let's say we are placing 5 orders on the book, top is tight, bottom is wide.
When widening based on vol, do I add the same N bps to all orders or multiply the spread by X factor instead?
Adding N bps won't matter for wide orders and might add too much to smaller orders.
What is your experience?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please clarify, are your 5 orders on the bid, ask, or ...? "widening based on vol" do you mean that the "volatility increases", but what does it means of the bid-ask spread does not change? the volatility on this specific instrument is the result on its past trades... Last but not least: what does "adding N bps" means? is it about adding more orders at the same prices?
